# How to we set the ng-cloak globally for the all controller in angular?

Tags: angularjs

For my angular js application, i wish to enable ng-cloak for all the controllers rather than adding in each template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in index.html body tag

Comment: Is this fine? 

<body ng-cloak>
<p>{{value}}</p>
</body>